# Program to print from a queue prints a number instead

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, structure

So here's the code I have at the moment.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct cake {
    char name;
    int waitTime;
    int prepTime;
    int bakeTime;
    int turnTime;
};

struct cake redVelvet(){
    struct cake c;
    c.name = "R";
    c.waitTime = 0;
    c.prepTime = 60;
    c.bakeTime = 30;
    c.turnTime = 0;
    return c;
};
struct Node {
    struct cake cake;
    struct Node* next;
};
// Two glboal variables to store address of front and rear nodes. 
struct Node* front = NULL;
struct Node* rear = NULL;

// To Enqueue an integer
void Enqueue(struct cake x) {
    struct Node* temp =
        (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->cake = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL){
        front = rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
}

// To Dequeue an integer.
void Dequeue() {
    struct Node* temp = front;
    if (front == NULL) {
        printf("Queue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }
    if (front == rear) {
        front = rear = NULL;
    }
    else {
        front = front->next;
    }
    free(temp);
}

struct cake Front() {
    if (front == NULL) {
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    return front->cake;
}

void Print() {
    struct Node* temp = front;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->cake.name);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main(void){

    Enqueue(redVelvet());
    Enqueue(redVelvet());
    Print();
    getchar();

}
```

So In reality I'm going to have many different cakes, and if certain conditions are meant they are going to be inputted into the queue of LinkedList. However as a sample I created one type of cake (Red Velvet) And added it into the queue via my enqueue function and then tried to print it, However my out put is "88   88"

I want it to print the name of the Cake instead.

Comment: You are using the `%d` format specifier for integers, so sure it prints an integer, and you are lucky that your program doesn't crash. `%s` is the specifier for strings.

Comment: Your cake name is a char, which is an small number and you are printing them as numbers using "%d". Change it to char*, and print them using" %s".

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() and family of functions.   always check (!= NULL) the returned value from malloc() and family of functions to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line in Enqueue(): 'temp->cake = x;' will copy a pointer,  what is actually needed is: 'memcpy(&(temp->cake), &x, sizeof( struct cake ) );'

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time to reply to me!

Answer (score 2):

Following 2 line of code change needed

```
c.name = 'R';
```

Inside print function formatter type should match the type of variable

```
 printf("%c ", temp->cake.name);
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. I changed it but now I get an error.

First-chance exception at 0x0FF6FB53 (msvcr120d.dll) in BakerySimulation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000052.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: `exception` is it C or C++?

Comment: C
But I fixed it, I had used %s, So I tried using %c and it worked. Btw I have another problem.

If I change the initial cake structure to say "char name[50]"
And then in the Red Velvet strucutre set C.name to "Red Velvet" It gives me a red underline under c.name (only the c part) and says it must be a modifiable value..

Comment: @RidwanSameer: When you change to `char name[50]`, then `c.name = "Red Velvet";` won't work as is. You might need `strcpy` (or its variants).

Comment: @Arun Hey, Thanks. I used a variant of the strcpy a while ago but that also gave some error. Could you give me a sample code for this? I think even when I sued strcopy it gave some error about it having to be modifiable.

Comment: @RidwanSameer:  Try `strcpy(c.name, "Red Velvet");` to begin with. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: @Arun Sorry forgot to reply, It works now. Thanks alot.